# how to resolve erreur prestashop WARNING translation Translation not found

Tags: debugging, prestashop, warnings, translation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRs6q.png)

presta version :1.7.6.1
Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u9

Comment: Please add some details on what are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: You just have to add the translation in your backoffice. (backoffice > International> Translations > Modify translations)